# Python: Take each item and iterate through all items in another list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two lists.

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
B=['a','b','c']
```

How do I iterate through all the elements of `B` for each element of list `A`.

Comment: Can you provide desired output too?

Comment: Take each item from `A` and concatinate with all the items of `B`. Like `1a,1b,1c,2a,2b,2c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess you want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for a, b in product(A, B):
    print(a, b)
```

which produces

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 a
2 b
2 c
3 a
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple list comprehension followed by string formatting

```
>>> ["{}{}".format(i,k) for i in A  for k in B]
>>> ['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2b', '2c', '3a', '3b', '3c', '4a', '4b', '4c', '5a', '5b', '5c', '6a', '6b', '6c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using nested For loops.

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
B=['a','b','c']
c=[]
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        c.append(str(i)+j)

print(c)
```

output:

```
['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2b', '2c', '3a', '3b', '3c', '4a', '4b', '4c', '5a', '5b', '5c', '6a', '6b', '6c']
```

Comment: I was expecting Pythonic method. This we all know.